# Scala: class type required but {generic type} found in trait

Tags: scala

I'm using Slick 3.0 and trying to create a trait to offer basic operations. Here is my trait:

```
object DAO {
  var db: Database = null
}

trait CommonAPI[T <: Table[_]] {
  private val db = DAO.db
  private val objects = TableQuery[T]

  def count: Future[Int] = db.run(objects.length.result)
  def insert(obj: T#TableElementType): Future[Int] = db.run(objects += obj)
  def all: Future[Seq[T]] = db.run(objects.result)
}
```

`DAO.db` is initialized in Play's `onStart` method. However, I met compilation error `class type required but T found` in line `private val objects = TableQuery[T]`.

What am I supposed to do? Thanks!

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

At first, define this to avoid class type issue..

```
class Service[T <: Table[_]](path: String, cons: Tag => T){

  lazy val db = Database.forConfig(path)

  def query = TableQuery[T](cons)
}
```

Then use it this way, Post is sub class of Table:

```
object Abcd {

  object Def extends Service[Post]("mydb", abc) {



    def test = {


      //db

      val q = query.drop(1).take(20)
      val r = db.run(q.result)

      println(q.result.statements.head)
      println(r)

      r

    }
  }

  private def abc(tag: Tag) = new Post(tag)

}
```

This solution tested ok.

Comment: Instead of the wrapping object you can write directly: `object Def extends Service[Post]("mydb", ((tag: Tag) => new Post(tag)))`. Alternatively, you can pass the TableQuery instead of the tag function: `object Def extends Service[Post]("mydb", (TableQuery[Post]))`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have done something similar. I used a bit different approach. I have one generic DAO and few(per resource/table) classes which just inherits for it.

this is generic DAO:

```
class BaseDbEntity[T <: BaseEntity, R <: BaseT[T]](val tableName: String, tableQuery: TableQuery[R]) extends DatabaseAccess{

  val createReturningId = tableQuery returning tableQuery.map{item => item.id}

  def create(entity: T): Int = {
    connectionPool withSession {
      implicit session =>
        val resId = createReturningId += entity
        resId
    }
  }

  def getAll = {
    connectionPool withSession {
      implicit session =>
        tableQuery.list
    }
  }
}
```

code of full class:
(https://github.com/vixxx123/scalasprayslickexample/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/vixxx123/scalasprayslickexample/database/BaseDbEntity.scala)

and Specific DAO with corresponding Table class:

```
class PersonDao extends BaseDbEntity[Person, PersonT]("person", TableQuery[PersonT])

class PersonT(tag: Tag) extends BaseT[Person](tag, "person") {
  def name: Column[String] = column[String]("name")
  def lastname: Column[String] = column[String]("lastname")

  override def * = (id.?, name, lastname) <> (
    (Person.apply _).tupled, Person.unapply)
}
```

you can find that class here: https://github.com/vixxx123/scalasprayslickexample/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/vixxx123/scalasprayslickexample/exampleapi/person/PersonDao.scala

Maybe it will help you out.

Comment: Is there any way to write a trait like what I want?

Comment: So,
to make it work as a trait your objecs val would need to be declared as a abstract method 
def objects: TableQuery[T]
and every time you would mix in that trait you would have to provide implementation of it.

Second approach would be that every method of your trait would take tableQuery as a param. That param could be implicit - so it wouldn't be so painful to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a tag instead and create table query from it , if your table class is defined as :

```
case class Sample(....)

class SampleTable(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[Sample](tag, "sample_table") {
    .....
}
```

then you can implement your generic trait as below :

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.Tag // here mysql is used , you can import the driver specific to your db

object DAO {
  var db: Database = null
}

trait CommonAPI[T, A<: Table[T]] {
  private val db = DAO.db
  private val tableTag : Tag => A = _
  def setTag(tag : Tag => A) = { tableTag = tag }
  private val objects = TableQuery(tableTag)

  def count: Future[Int] = db.run(objects.length.result)
  def insert(obj: T#TableElementType): Future[Int] = db.run(objects += obj)
  def all: Future[Seq[T]] = db.run(objects.result)
}
```

Comment: tableTag should be a "var" not a "val"